# TensorFlow model throws a dimensional error after creation

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

i have a dataframe of 110200x28 to put as input in a 100x28 fashion (100 is a timestep) into a network to perform 1d convolution and finally output 3 targets. So i construct the following model:

```
#building model
def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(100,28)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(28,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.99))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=16,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.99))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.99))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.99))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    #model.add(layers.Reshape((1,179200), input_shape=(100,28,64)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation = 'linear'))

    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=['mean_squared_error'],
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()]
    )
    return model


model = build_model()


#train model and output
history = model.fit(
    dataframes,
    targets,
    epochs=50,
    #validation_data=(
    #   x_val,
    #   y_val
    #),
    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        #monitor = 'val_loss',
        patience = 4)
    ]
)
print(history.history)
```

but when i press run it outputs this weird error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-338e16e136c3> in <module>
     41     callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
     42         #monitor = 'val_loss',
---> 43         patience = 4)
     44     ]
     45 )

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    577             feed_input_shapes,
    578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 579             exception_prefix='input')
    580 
    581         if y is not None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_26 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (110200, 28)
```

now from what i understand the 3rd dimension should be there because it is the batch size and is automatically given in by the programm. Could you help me maybe identify what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframes.reshape(dataframes.shape[0],dataframes.shape[1], 1) # add this line

#train model and output
history = model.fit(
    dataframes,
    targets,
    epochs=50,
    #validation_data=(
    #   x_val,
    #   y_val
    #),
    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        #monitor = 'val_loss',
        patience = 4)
    ]
)
print(history.history)
```

Your model needs 3d data, so add an extra dimension at the end.

Comment: Did you add the reshape before fit?

Comment: i ficed it but now i wrote :
'targets=targets.reshape(1,targets.shape[0],targets.shape[1]) # add this line'
and am getting this error now:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_7 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 110200, 28)


i want it to take in 100 of these 110200 do you know how to do it?

Comment: Why are you reshaping target? This reshping doesn't make any sense. This will give you error.